# Sensitivity plot analysis asymmetric

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am doing meta-analysis on R for which I did influence analysis. For the leave out of one method, the confidence intervals are overlapping with the labels on the right.

Any idea on how to solve it? For the influence analysis I got the code from the following link. I was using ggplo2, ggrepel and gridExtra pacakage along with this. When I run the analysis it gives an error that replace size with linewidth though I have no clue where to replace it in the ggplot2 as I just installed it from CRAN. I would appreciate any help as I am just a medschool student doing some basic analysis on R

[The sensitivity analysis plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4URKs.png)

[website for code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MathiasHarrer/dmetar/master/R/influence.analysis.R)

```
# assessment of peak velocity
library(meta)
library(metafor)
library(ggplo2)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)

    velocity_Authors <- c("Okonko 2008 (FERRIC HF)", "Veldhuisen 2017 (EFFECT HF)", "Dhoot 2020", "Martens 2021 (IRON CRT)")
    velocity_MD <- c(-2.2, 1.04, -2, 1.37)
    velocity_SE <- c(1.34, 0.44, 1.03, 0.58)

    pv <- data.frame(Authors = velocity_Authors, MD = velocity_MD, SE = velocity_SE)
    print(pv)
    peak_velocity <- metagen(TE = pv$MD ,
                                 seTE = pv$SE,
                                 studlab = pv$Authors,
                                 data = pv,
                                 sm = "MD",
                                 fixed = FALSE,
                                 random = TRUE,
                                 method.tau = "REML",
                                 hakn = TRUE,
                                 title = "Peak velocity")
    summary(ejection_fraction)
    forest(peak_velocity, comb.random = TRUE, text.random = "Random Effects Model, REML", label.left = "Favors Placebo",label.right = "Favors IV iron", print.I2.ci = FALSE, col.square = "red", col.predict = "black", col.diamond = "royalblue", label.e = "IV Iron", label.c =  "Placebo", test.overall = TRUE, ff.heading = "bold", cex = 6, smlab = "Mean difference 
           IV, Random, 95% CI")  
    peak_velocity_influence <- InfluenceAnalysis(peak_velocity, random = TRUE)
    print(peak_velocity_influence)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)